# Is there a css selector for selecting an element futherup in the html?

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

In the following HTML, I want to apply a hover effect to the header `h2`, upon hover of the image `img`. Is there a css selector to do that, or another way?

HTML

```
  <article>
      <h2><a href="#">Title</a></h2>
      <a href="#"><img src="#" /></a>
  </article>
```

Comment: You can do this by jquery. this is currently not possible by css.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Update: The subject specifier appears to have been removed from the *Editor’s Draft, 6 May 2014* of the Selectors Level 4 specification. This leaves no way to achieve this using CSS.

---

Selectors Level 4 introduces the [subject specifier](http://www.w3.org/TR/2013/WD-selectors4-20130502/#subject) which allows:

```
!h2 + a img:hover { }
```

to select the `<h2>`.

Browser support is, AFAIK, currently non-existent.

You can simulate it in JavaScript (the following is untested, but should give you the idea).

```
var img = document.querySelector('h2 + a img');
img.addEventListener('mouseover', function (e) {
    this.parentNode.previousElementSibling.className += " hovered";
});
img.addEventListener('mouseout', function (e) {
    this.parentNode.previousElementSibling.className = this.parentNode.previousElementSibling.className.replace(/\shovered/g, "");
});
```

Answer (score 2):

There is actualy no way to do it in pure CSS.

But, you could simply do the following :

```
<article>
    <a href="#">
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <img src="#" />
    </a>
</article>
```

And then apply the :hover effect to the `a` tag.

Another way will be with some javascript. For example, with the jquery selector `.closest()`

Comment: Wouldn't it be weird to wrap an entire block of content in an anchor? Or is that still somewhat ok?

Comment: No matter with that, `a` tag can wrap anything. I use this solution in a lot of websites, for example with some articles : <a>Title, Pic, Description</a>

Answer (score 1):

"*Is there a **css** selector to do that?*"

This doesn't exist in the current state of CSS *yet* (as of [Selectors Level 3)](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/) .. but when [Selectors Level 4](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/) is more widely implemeneted, there will be a parent selector:

```
E! > F - "An E element, parent of an F element"
```

Unfortuntely it will be quite some time before this is implemented as the Module is still in the Working Draft stage ..

Comment: Although, in this case, the `h2` is not a parent of the `img`.

Answer (score -1):

You could perhaps try a simple workaround, something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">

<style media="all">
h2 {position: relative; padding-bottom: 100px; line-height: 1.5em;}
h2 img {position: absolute; left: 0; top: 1.5em; width: 100px; height: 100px; background: yellow;}
h2 a:hover {color: red;}
</style>

</head>
<body>

<article>
    <h2><a href="#">Title <img src="#" /></a></h2>
</article>

</body>
</html>
```

This is a rough hewn experiment, but no doubt could be refined. It's also legal, in HTML5, to nest the heading (and image) inside the `a`, but I'm not a great fan of that.

Comment: I'm not fan about putting an image inside a `h` tag, and with your solution will you put the description too ? <h2><a>title, pic, <div>description</div></a></h2> ?? I think that it's uglier than putting everything inside the `a` tag...

Comment: I wouldn't put any block level elements like `<div>` inside the `<a>`. I was basing my answer on the OP's original code.

Comment: a {display:block;} img {display:block;background:#CC;padding:5px;}... that's it ;p