# CSS notation: the meaning of ">"

Tags: html, css

In my website, I have the following structure on some html page:

```
<html>
     <head><!-- All the usual information here, including the link to the css file --></head>
     <body>
           <div id="splash">
                 <!-- The good stuff -->
           </div><!--End of Splash-->
     </body>
</html>
```

Now that `#splash` div only appears on that one html page, and I need the css affecting that page's `html {}` to be a little different. Is the below notation going to do what I need?

```
html>body#splash {/* CSS that only affects the html that contains div #splash */}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a css selector for selecting an element futherup in the html?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280632/is-there-a-css-selector-for-selecting-an-element-futherup-in-the-html)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're looking for a parent selector; sadly [this doesn't exist in CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector), so you're out of luck.

This is, from what I understand, mostly for performance reasons -- [Jonathan Snook's article](http://snook.ca/archives/html_and_css/css-parent-selectors) goes into a little more detail.

It's either time to change your page generation so that a class or ID gets added to the `html` element on your "splash" page, or resort to JavaScript, such as the jQuery [cssParentSelector library](https://github.com/Idered/cssParentSelector) that arkanciscan mentions.

Comment: Thank you, indeed you are right the word I was looking for was 'parent' - I had not used child selectors before and I thought they meant something else.

Answer (score 2):

Since IDs are unique, you can just do:

```
#splash {
    /* stuff */
}
```

About your question:

```
html>body#splash
```

Will not work; try

```
html>body #splash
```

The `>` is basically the same this as a space, but selects only direct children.

(I'm assuming you're trying to select `#splash`; that's how I read your question. If you want to select `body` if `#splash` exists, then... well, you can't.)

Comment: This would select `#splash`, not `html`.

Comment: @Joey That's what the OP's trying to do, if I'm not mistaken

Comment: @Doorknob — It isn't. Reread the paragraph of text between the two code examples in the question.

Comment: @Quentin Ah, okay then. Well then it's impossible, until CSS4 is adopted (in a long time, and then we'll still have to worry about supporting old IEs)

Answer (score 2):

Like others have said, you can't do this is CSS... yet! In the next version of CSS you'll be able to add an exclamation point to any part of a compound selector to indicate which element of the selector your rules should apply to. This will be called a "subject" (http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors4/#subject)

If you want to use this today you can try this polyfill https://github.com/Idered/cssParentSelector

Answer (score 1):

Child selectors are indicated by `>`: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#child-selectors

It means you are selecting a first-level descendent.

Your code needs this space:

```
  html>body #splash
```

This reads: "Select the element with the id of `splash` that is a descendent of `body` which is a child of `html`."

Your code is this:

```
 html>body#splash
```

Your current code reads: "Select the body element with the id of `splash` that is a child of `html`.

Answer (score 1):

As has been said, this can't be done in current CSS.

But just to give you a suggestion: you could add a unique ID or a class to the HTML in question; if you know which one it is ahead of time, just add it statically; if not, you'll have to actually look (with JS) if there's a `div` like you describe in the body, you can't do it with CSS alone.