# CSS Selector Table element of a Cell element

Tags: html, css

I am wondering if this is possible.

I have the following html table with a large html files (with other tables):

```
<table>
   <tbody>
      <tr>
         <td class="someCell"></td>
      </tr>
   </tbody>
</table>
```

Is there a CSS selector to select the table element of the cell with class someCell?

Comment: In jquery you can do something like this jQuery('.someCell').parent().parent().parent() now the selected element would be table

Comment: This is a great idea, but I can only affect the CSS.  I am trying to style the table.

Comment: that styling you can do jQuery('.someCell').parent().parent().parent().attr('style',"whatever style you want to apply")

Comment: Not possible select parents with CSS . In Jquery must be just `parents()`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a css selector for selecting an element futherup in the html?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280632/is-there-a-css-selector-for-selecting-an-element-futherup-in-the-html)

Comment: @Quentin very similar.  Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is currently no way to select the parent of an element in CSS, but the following works with jQuery:

`$(".someCell").parents('table').addClass("someClass");`