# Style parent of text input CSS

Tags: html, css

I have a text input that is wrapped inside a div. I want to change a css attribute of the :after of the parent div when the input is focused. How can I do this in CSS?

```
<div class="dataInputTextContainer">
    <input class="dataInputText"  />
</div>
```

I tried this but it did not work:

```
.dataInputText:FOCUS ~ .dataInputTextContainer:after{
    background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a css selector for selecting an element futherup in the html?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16280632/is-there-a-css-selector-for-selecting-an-element-futherup-in-the-html)

Comment: Red background indicates an error as per the general UX rules. Not recommended.

Comment: Use javascript instead

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Simply put, you cant

(sorry)

CSS works in terms of DOM decendancy, in that rules can only be constructed for elements which appear subsequently in the DOM. As such, you cannot select a parent, or even previous sibling.

What I would tend to suggest is that you sit down, take a step back and work out what you are trying to accomplish. 99% of the time either someone else out there has done it, or you can do it with a minor change to either your CSS or HTML.

Incidentally, a solution would **not** be to try and style `:before` or `:after` on the `input`, it is a replaced element  so such elements do not apply. Why not simply add a `label` for the `input` and style it?

Answer (score 0):

If you didn't apply style on :after of the parent but rather put a tag at the same level than the `input`, you could have used this syntax to apply style of the sibling tag.